# NPM semver resolution

Tags: npm, semantic-versioning

I’m brand new to npm, and I need to get list of all possible versions for specified package and semver. Similar that npm semver calculator is doing. For ex.: with entry data: package: tape, semver:’~2.10.1’, result should be:[ 2.10.1, 2.10.2, 2.10.3].
Could you please recommend how to get this. Ideally, I need this in python. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This would probably be easier in node because the [`semver`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/semver) package. I found the [`semantic_version`](https://pypi.org/project/pynpm/) python package but it doesn't work on all [ranges](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver.html) (i.e. `1.x`) but looks to cover most of them, including [caret](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver.html#caret-ranges-123-025-004) and [tilde](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver.html#tilde-ranges-123-12-1) ranges.

```py
import requests
from semantic_version import Spec, Version

def get_npm_versions(package, range):
    # Make get request to npm registry for given package
    response = requests.get('https://registry.npmjs.org/%s'%(package))

    # Check for good response
    if response.status_code == 200:
        # Parse response
        data = response.json()
        # Convert unicode to strings
        versions = map(str, data['versions'].keys())
        # Convert strings to `Version`s
        versions = map(Version, versions)
        # Create range `Spec`
        range_spec = Spec(range)

        return range_spec.filter(versions)
    else:
        raise Exception('NPM registry not reachable :(')

# Use function with to get `tape@~2.10.1`
versions = get_npm_versions('tape', '~2.10.1')

for v in versions:
    print v
```